# How can I update every fields data when remove rows

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb

I'm looking for an way to update some rows right after I deleted some rows on MariaDB.

For examples, my talbes are look like:

```
--------------------------------------
| main_id |  name   | value | sub_id |
--------------------------------------
|   1     | DRINKS  | 1000  |  COKE  |
|   1     | DRINKS  | 2000  |  BEER  |
|   1     | DRINKS  | 0600  | WATER  |
|   2     | SALAD   | 2000  | Peanut |
|   3     | BREADS  | 1500  | FLAT   |
|   3     | BREADS  | 1000  | TOAST  |
|   4     | BEEF    | 3000  | SAUSAGE|
...
```

When I remove `'2' SALAD`, I want to update every rows main_id to main_id-1 like

```
--------------------------------------
| main_id |  name   | value | sub_id |
--------------------------------------
|   1     | DRINKS  | 1000  |  COKE  |
|   1     | DRINKS  | 2000  |  BEER  |
|   1     | DRINKS  | 0600  | WATER  |
|   2     | BREADS  | 1500  | FLAT   |
|   2     | BREADS  | 1000  | TOAST  |
|   3     | BEEF    | 3000  | SAUSAGE|
...
//  |   2     | SALAD   | 2000  | Peanut | has removed so every main_id updated.
```

I cannot use PRIMARY KEY, because the things are so many duplicated.

If I have to join every rows, then I'm worried about performance, so I cannot find the way to solve the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what's the criteria of deletion? and what's the thing that uniquely identifies this row?

Comment: did you think about trigger?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo sorry I don't have unique ID. jusy index for key

Comment: @GiacomoM Also thanks for the trigger :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the Delete statement :

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE main_id = 2;
```

an Update statement containing Analytic Functions might be issued provided your DB version is 10.2+ :

```
UPDATE t
  JOIN (WITH t2 AS
       (
        SELECT LAG(main_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY main_id) AS lg, t.* 
          FROM t
       )
       SELECT t2.*,
              1 + SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(lg,main_id) = main_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) 
              OVER (ORDER BY main_id) AS new_id
         FROM t2 ) t2
    ON t.main_id = t2.main_id           
   SET t.main_id = t2.new_id;
```

to get main_id - 1 is updated for main_id column for main_id >2 for this individual case.

A Delete Trigger containing an Update cannot be applied on the same because of mutating trigger problem.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=72557fd3ca5cd7e799cb1f7e4548ec61)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!! 
I have a few questions, and sorry for my low skills that,
is t a table for copying t or calculating t?
and where ` lg ` come from?

I ran your demo, and I really think appreciate for the demo, I cannot find any lg or t2.

and for the last question, would it cause some performance issue that if I update every rows?

Comment: Sorry, my english is too bad, I know where t2 is come from, just wonder that is it just for calculating? I cannot edit above comment.
Thanks for your help :<3:

Comment: hi @EugeneFitzher I woke up :) You're welcome. `t` is assumed to be your original table and `t2` is a derived(calculated) one. e.g just for calculating, since one more step is needed to get a value from analytic functions such as LAG in this case, in order to use(`lg`) in the next step.

Comment: @ Barbaros Ozhan
Thanks a lot!